# Nouveau error while installing Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation

I am sharing the screenshot of an error. I am trying to install Ubuntu.
Is this a hardware or software issue?

```
nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 100c80 [ IBUS ]
```

[image]

Laptop: Acer Aspire 5, i5 8th gen, 4GB RAM; GPU: NVidia GeForce MX150, Intel UHD Graphics 620.

Comment: What video card? What brand/model system? Often you need nomodeset or with newest 20.04 the safe boot option. https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: Please specify your video card and device. Is it a PC? Is it a laptop? If it's a laptop, does it have switchable graphics, i.e. a builtin GPU and a discrete GPU?

Comment: If you can still proceed with install, use the proprietary drivers after. Open source nvidia drivers are not good.

Comment: Laptop : acer aspire 5 , i5 8th gen, 4gb ram ; gpu : nvidia geforce mx150 , intel uhd graphics 620. Installed graphics drivers from nvidia website.  What do you mean by proprietary drivers.

Comment: Also earlier i was running ubuntu 18.0.4 on same machine in dual boot. I have deleted the ubuntu now when i again installing it this above error i am getting.